# Vertical align in Materialize CSS

Tags: css, materialize

I'm trying to center a form on the screen using Materialize. I tried everything, but I can not do it for all resolutions and also be responsive. In certain resolutions it works perfect, but when you add or remove controls (), in some resolutions it looks good, in others it goes wrong. Some help? Thank you!

**Code**

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Test</title>
  <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.1/css/materialize.min.css">
  <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

  <style>
    .card {
      margin: 1rem 0 1rem 0 !important;
    }
    
    .card .card-title {
      background-color: #26a69a;
    }
    
    .card-title span {
      display: block;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 5px;
    }
    
    .card-content {
      padding: 30px;
    }
    
    .valign {
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .valign-wrapper {
      width: 100%;
      background: url("http://vunature.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/trees-woods-tree-nature-path-forest-landscape-amazing-pictures-of-wallpapers.jpg") no-repeat;
    }
    
    .circle {
      display: block;
      margin: 10px auto;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <header class="navbar-fixed">
    <nav class="top-nav">
      <div class="nav-wrapper grey darken-3">
        <a class="brand-logo center" href="#">Logo</a>
        <ul class="right">
          <li>
            <a href="#" id="registerLink">Register</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" id="loginLink">Log in</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <div class="valign-wrapper">
    <div class="valign">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-title white-text">
            <span>Register</span>
          </div>
          <div class="card-content">
            <p>
              Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
            </p>
            <form action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="externalRegisterForm" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
              <div class="validation-summary-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-summary="true">
                <ul>
                  <li style="display:none" />
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div>
                <section style="position: absolute; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%); display: none;">
                  <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Sign In">
                  <input type="submit" class="btn" value="x">
                </section>
                <img class="circle" src="https://images.google.com/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png" width="128" height="128" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s12 m4 l4 xl4">
                  <input class="validate" data-val="true" data-val-required="El campo Nombre de usuario es obligatorio." id="UserName" name="UserName" type="text" />
                  <label for="UserName" class="active">Username</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-field col s12 m4 l4 xl4">
                  <input class="validate" data-val="true" data-val-required="El campo Nombre(s) es obligatorio." id="Name" name="Name" type="text" />
                  <label for="Name" class="active">Name</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-field col s12 m4 l4 xl4">
                  <input class="validate" data-val="true" data-val-required="El campo Apellido(s) es obligatorio." id="LastName" name="LastName" type="text" />
                  <label for="LastName" class="active">Last name</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                  <input class="validate" data-val="true" data-val-required="El campo Email es obligatorio." id="Email" name="Email" type="text" />
                  <label for="Email" class="active">Email</label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="card-action">
            <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Sign In" form="externalRegisterForm" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.1/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $('.button-collapse').sideNav();
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

**EDIT**

https://image.ibb.co/h7ESBk/1.jpg

See the white line below. It is a resolution of 1366x768. If you add more input, it looks "normal" and responsive. But if you delete an input you can see how the white background is larger.

Comment: Can you give us a resolution where it doesn't look how you want it to?

Comment: @TW80000 Thanks for answering. I edited the post.

Comment: So your problem is that you don't want to see the white background at the bottom of the page when the page content is not tall enough to use up the whole screen?

Comment: @TW80000 Exactly, I need the image to occupy the entire white background and I want to center the form, regardless of how many controls it has and the resolution of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the feedback you gave in the comments, I think all you need is to add `min-height: calc(100vh - 64px);` to `.valign-wrapper`.

That will fill the whole page. You may have to modify the `background` property as well to make sure the image fills up the whole element, I couldn't load the image so I couldn't test that. The vertical alignment is already working.

Before: [image]

After: [image]

Comment: You are my new best friend. Thank you. The problem was that I used height = calc (100% - 64px). I also have to make use of @media because in resolutions smaller than 600px, it is no longer 64px, it is 56px. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

These UI libraries have been offering a 'grid' solution to this for some time now. However, I find vanilla CSS flexbox (whether hard coded or scripted with JS in the browser) to be super easy for centering both ways.

As for breakpoints, you will need them. I went thru all this on this here project https://github.com/rhroyston/firebase-v4-auth. Feel free to copy& paste as you need. Snippet below.

```
//ON LOAD INITIALLY ASSUME PHONE
var width = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
doc.getElementById("title").style.display = "flex";
doc.getElementById("title-right").style.display = "none";
if (width >= 840) {
    //IT'S A DESKTOP
    doc.getElementById("title").style.display = "none";
    doc.getElementById("title-right").style.display = "flex";
}
else if (width >= 480) {
    //IT'S A TABLET
    doc.getElementById("title").style.display = "flex";
    doc.getElementById("title-right").style.display = "none";
}
//ON RESIZE INITIALLY ASSUME PHONE
window.addEventListener("resize", resizeThrottler, false);
var resizeTimeout;
function actualResizeHandler() {
    // assuming device is a phone
    doc.getElementById("title").style.display = "flex";
    doc.getElementById("title-right").style.display = "none";
    if (window.innerWidth >= 840) {
        //device is a desktop
        doc.getElementById("title").style.display = "none";
        doc.getElementById("title-right").style.display = "flex";
    }
    else if (window.innerWidth >= 480) {
        //device is a tablet
        doc.getElementById("title").style.display = "none";
        doc.getElementById("title-right").style.display = "flex";
    }
}
function resizeThrottler() {
    // ignore resize events as long as an actualResizeHandler execution is in the queue
    if (!resizeTimeout) {
        resizeTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
            resizeTimeout = null;
            actualResizeHandler();
            // The actualResizeHandler will execute at a rate of 15fps
        }, 66);
    }
}
```